# parse json in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, json

I load a php/json file. This is my json file:

```
echo '{';
echo '"position":[';
while($inhoud = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo '{';
  echo '"lat":"'.$inhoud['lat'].'",';
  echo '"long":"'.$inhoud['long'].'",';
  echo '}';

}

echo ']}';
```

This works. I want to load it in my javascript and do it like this:

```
$.getJSON('req/position.php', function(data) { 
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
    newLatLng = key;
});
});
```

but this doesn't work. It loads the file but i don't get this data. What should i do?

Thanks,

Comment: Define *"this doesn't work"*. What happens that's different from what you expect to happen? What error messages do you receive, if any? What does the javascript console output in your browser when you try to accomplish whatever it is that *"doesn't work?"*

Comment: well, nothing. It loads the file and then nothing. I add an alert but this didn't fire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your co-ordinates defined in the array named `position`. You need to iterate through that. The Array contains objects with the properties `lat` and `long`. If you want to use the values, you should try something like:

```
$.getJSON('req/position.php'), function(data){
    $.each(data.position, function(index, value){
        var newLatLng = { latitude: value.lat, longitude: value.long };
    });
});
```

Comment: i do this:
$.getJSON('req/position.php'), function(data){
    $.each(data.position, function(index, value){
        alert('success');
    });
};

but i don't get an alert.

Answer (score 5):

I think you have some syntax errors in the JSON output.

- When you output `"long"` data, you append a comma `,` at the end, but you should not, because `"long"` is the last key of the object.
- You print out an object in a `while` cycle. These objects are part of an array. So, except for the last one, you have to append a comma `,` after the closing `}`.

And, if I can ask, why you are not using the **[`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)** PHP function, instead of build all the JSON string *manually*? With it, you build all the data as normal PHP array, and then encode (translate) it in JSON. You will avoid all these annoying syntax stuffs.

Just try it:

```
$data = array();
$data['position'] = array();

while($inhoud = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $data['position'][] = array(
        "lat" => $inhoud['lat'],
        "long" => $inhoud['long']
    );
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: i changed my json to this code. I was not aware of the json_encode. Really nice! Thanks. It didn't fixed the script though but i am happy with this clean way

Answer (score 1):

Return proper header in PHP script
`header('Content-type: application/json');`
And it should work.

Also use `json_encode` to encode PHP values into valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Constructing JSON in php through strings works but is primitive. Start constructing an array and use json_encode().

```
$arr = array();

while($inhoud = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $temp = array();
  $temp['lat'] = $inhoud['lat'];
  $temp['long'] = $inhoud['long'];
  $arr[] = $temp;
}

echo json_encode($arr);
```

If all that you select in your mysql query is 'lat' and 'long' you could also just place `$inhoud` into `$arr` inside your while loop like so.

```
while($inhoud = mysql_fetch_array($result)){      
  $arr[] = $inhoud;
}
```

If you do this just make sure you only select columns in your mysql query that you would want to output in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON('req/position.php', function(data) {
   var obj = JSON.parse(data);
   // At this point, obj is an object with your JSON data.
});
```

Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON)